# how to keep agora from showing sensitive user data in the browser console

Tags: reactjs, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

[image]

Here you can see that in the console you can see the memberId as their email address. Any way to hide that or remove these updates from the console? I get them anytime someone enters or leaves a group chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the logs using the AgoraRTC Logger.

Example: `AgoraRTC.Logger.setLogLevel(AgoraRTC.Logger.NONE)`

Refer this documentation link:
https://docs.agora.io/en/All/API%20Reference/web/modules/agorartc.logger.html#setloglevel

Answer (score 1):

For agora 4.x sdk;
according to documentation at https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/iagorartc.html#setloglevel

```
AgoraRTC.setLogLevel(1);

The output log level.

0: DEBUG. Output all API logs.
1: INFO. Output logs of the INFO, WARNING and ERROR level.
2: WARNING. Output logs of the WARNING and ERROR level.
3: ERROR. Output logs of the ERROR level.
4: NONE. Do not output any log.
```